# Finding the percentages of categorical variables ( Good and Bad ) for Each Subject ID

Tags: r

When I try to get the percentages, the figure I get is not correct. For example, from the data frame below subject ID : 1 has 100% of good and 0% of bad. But my code does not give me this outcome.

```
performance <- tribble(
~SubjectID, ~Outcome,
1, 'good',
1, 'good',
1, 'good',
2, 'good',
2, 'bad',
2, 'good',
3, 'bad',
4, 'good',
4, 'good'
)

# finding the frequency
freq_id <- with(performance, table(SubjectID, Outcome))
view(freq_id)
#finding the percentage and rounding it up by 2
round(prop.table(freq_id)*100,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `margin` by default uses `c(1, 2)` i.e. row/column.  We need by row i.e. `1`

```
round(proportions(freq_id, 1) * 100, 2)
            Outcome
SubjectID    bad   good
        1   0.00 100.00
        2  33.33  66.67
        3 100.00   0.00
        4   0.00 100.00
```

It could be also written in `base R` pipe `|>`

```
performance |> 
   with(data = _, table(SubjectID, Outcome)) |>
   proportions(margin = 1) |>
   `*`(x = _, 100) |> 
   round(2)
      Outcome
SubjectID    bad   good
        1   0.00 100.00
        2  33.33  66.67
        3 100.00   0.00
        4   0.00 100.00
```

---

Or we can also use the `adorn_` functions in `janitor` to get the required formatted output

```
library(janitor)
library(dplyr)
performance %>%
    tabyl(SubjectID, Outcome) %>%
    adorn_percentages() %>%
    adorn_pct_formatting(digits = 2)
 SubjectID     bad    good
         1   0.00% 100.00%
         2  33.33%  66.67%
         3 100.00%   0.00%
         4   0.00% 100.00%
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `group_by()` function from the dplyr package makes this pretty straight forward.

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
performance <- tribble(
   ~SubjectID, ~Outcome,
   1, 'good',
   1, 'good',
   1, 'good',
   2, 'good',
   2, 'bad',
   2, 'good',
   3, 'bad',
   4, 'good',
   4, 'good'
)

performance %>% group_by(SubjectID) %>% 
            summarize("perGood" = sum(Outcome="good")/n())

# A tibble: 4 × 2
  SubjectID perGood
      <dbl>   <dbl>
1         1   1    
2         2   0.667
3         3   0    
4         4   1
```